# I'm having trouble making a discord bot that plays music

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots, ytdl

The bot successfully connects to the voice channel, but does not play the song from the URL I typed, the code is:

```
if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + "join"))
{
  message.channel.send("Entrando a " + message.member.voiceChannel);
  if (message.member.voiceChannel) 
  {
    const permissions = message.member.voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
    if (!permissions.has('CONNECT')) 
    {
      return message.channel.send('No me puedo conectar a ese canal')
    }
    if (!permissions.has('SPEAK')) {
      return message.channel.send('No puedo hablar en ese canal')
    }

    let connection = await message.member.voiceChannel.join();
    let dispatcher = connection.playStream(ytdl('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PLRrL9OsAF8&t=18s'))
      .on('start', () => {
        message.reply('Empieza la musica');
      })
      .on('end', () => {
          message.reply('Termino la musica');
          message.member.voiceChannel.leave();
      })
      .on('error', error => {
          message.reply('Error al intentar reproducir la cancion');
      });
    dispatcher.setVolumeLogarithmic(5 / 5);
  } 
  else 
  {
    message.reply('Tenes que estar dentro de un chat de voz');
  }
}
```

Can anyone identify a potential cause for this?

Comment: Debug and get more details about the problem. Is an error displayed on the console? Does something happen when you try to execute the command to listen to music on the discord? Add more information to your question, it is very empty

Comment: @Aks Jacoves Hi, thanks for comment, the error isn't displayed on the console, it is assumed that with the "join" command the bot enters the voice channel and automatically plays the song from the URL, the problem is that when i run the command the bot connects to the voice channel, but does not play the song.

Answer (score 0):

From what i can tell you are using Discord.js V11 which isn't the recomennded version(V12)

From the docs though it seems that maybe you have to pass a optional argument to ytdl

```
// Play streams using ytdl-core
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const streamOptions = { seek: 0, volume: 1 };
voiceChannel.join()
    .then(connection => {
    const stream = ytdl('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XAWgeLF9EVQ', { filter : 'audioonly' });
    const dispatcher = connection.playStream(stream, streamOptions);
})
.catch(console.error);
```

If that doesn't work Discord.js's Support server can be found [here](https://discord.gg/bRCvFy9). They officially moved to V12 in march but they might still help you